# cant get my for loop to give me the least common letter from my hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have everything working except I cant figure out why my code wont find the least common letter I have a for loop that is supposed to find the least common letter but it isn't giving me anything. it gives me the most common but not the least.

```
    FileReader file = new FileReader("\\src\\alphaCounter\\");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

    HashMap<Character,Integer> myHashSet = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    myHashSet.put('a', 0);
    /** this goes to Z


    int mostCommon = 0;
    char mostCommonLtr = ' ';
    int leastCommont = 0;
    char leastCommonLtr = ' ';



    Object[] words = reader.lines().toArray();

    /**
     * this loop has changed all the letters to lower case
     */
    for(Object word : words){
        String wordString = word.toString();
        wordString = wordString.toLowerCase();
        /**
         * 
         */
        if(wordString.length() > bigWord.length()){
            bigWord = wordString;
        }    
        for(int alpha = 0; alpha < wordString.length(); alpha++){
            myHashSet.put(wordString.charAt(alpha), myHashSet.get(wordString.charAt(alpha)) + 1);
        }

    }

            for(int alpha = 'a'; alpha<= 'z'; alpha++){
        System.out.println("The number of " + (char)alpha +  "'s in the words.txt = " + myHashSet.get((char)alpha ));

        if(myHashSet.get((char)alpha) > mostCommon)  {
            mostCommonLtr = (char)alpha;
            mostCommon = myHashSet.get((char)alpha); 
            /**
             * this gave me the most common letter
             */


        if(myHashSet.get((char)alpha) < leastCommont)  {
            leastCommonLtr = (char)alpha;
            leastCommont = myHashSet.get((char)alpha);
            /**
             * this was supposed to give me the least common
             */
        }   
    }


    System.out.println("The letter that appeared the least is " + leastCommonLtr);  

    System.out.println("The letter that appears the most is " + mostCommonLtr);
```

Comment: How are you initializing `leastCommont`?

Comment: Post a sample input and the expected, actual output

Comment: my code prints this message                                                                                                 "The letter that appeared the least is " 
   for least it should tell me j based off of my file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if(myHashSet.get((char)alpha) != null && myHashSet.get((char)alpha) > mostCommon)  {
                    mostCommonLtr = (char)alpha;
                    mostCommon = myHashSet.get((char)alpha); 
                    /**
                     * this gave me the most common letter
                     */
                } 

                if(myHashSet.get((char)alpha) != null && myHashSet.get((char)alpha) > leastCommont && alpha != mostCommonLtr )  {
                    leastCommonLtr = (char)alpha;
                    leastCommont = myHashSet.get((char)alpha);
                    /**
                     * this was supposed to give me the least common
                     */

            }
```

Try using the above piece of code. You have got the Highest and Lowest in the same if clause. you need to handle it differently. From the earlier code, it was not even coming to the least used character.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**

`int leastCommont = 0;`

**With**

`int leastCommont = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

**Reason**

With `leastCommont` initialized to 0, the following condition of your code is never satisfied:

`if(myHashSet.get((char)alpha) < leastCommont)`

Comment: @Lock13B If you get the answer to your question, please do not forget to mark the question as answered by accepting the answer that answered it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you. I made a simple char counter. You can make a function what you want using this. if you want to case-insentitive, make input string to lower or upper case.

```
    String wordString = "a1s3df2ad2fsa3dfwe3wrqasdf";
    System.out.println("input string="+wordString) ;
    char[] cword = wordString.toCharArray();
    List<Character> mylist = new ArrayList<Character>();
    Set<Character> charset = new HashSet<Character>();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> myHashSet = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    int maxcnt, mincnt;
    for (char c : cword) {
        mylist.add(c);
        charset.add(c);
    }
    for (Character c : charset) {
        int freq= Collections.frequency(mylist, c) ;
        System.out.println("alpha " + c + " freq="+freq );
        myHashSet.put(c, freq) ;
    }
    maxcnt = Collections.max(myHashSet.values()) ;
    mincnt = Collections.min(myHashSet.values()) ;
    System.out.println("maxcnt="+maxcnt+" mincnt="+mincnt) ;

    // get max alpha
    System.out.print("max count alphas: ") ;
    for (Character c : charset ) {
        if ( maxcnt == myHashSet.get(c).intValue() ) {
            System.out.print(" "+c);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("") ;
    // get min alpha
    System.out.print("min count alphas: ") ;
    for (Character c : charset ) {
        if ( mincnt == myHashSet.get(c).intValue() ) {
            System.out.print(" "+c);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("") ;
```

sample's output

```
input string=a1s3df2ad2fsa3dfwe3wrqasdf
alpha a freq=4
alpha 1 freq=1
alpha q freq=1
alpha 2 freq=2
alpha r freq=1
alpha s freq=3
alpha 3 freq=3
alpha d freq=4
alpha e freq=1
alpha f freq=4
alpha w freq=2
maxcnt=4 mincnt=1
max count alphas:  a d f
min count alphas:  1 q r e
```